# How to add a custom user taxonomy column to "All Users" in users.php?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, users

I am trying to add a custom user taxonomy column to "All Users" table in users.php  using `show_admin_column` like that:

```
register_taxonomy( 'marketing-channel', 'Marketing Channel', 'Marketing Channel',  array('user'), array(
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'show_tagcloud'         => false,
        'meta_box_cb'           => null,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '',
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'rewrite'               => true,
        'sort'                  => '',
    ));
```

But it wont add it automatically like it does on a post type table.

How to add a custom user taxonomy column to "All Users" in users.php?

Comment: does you code work and add taxonomy in user.php? you are missing single quotation in your code.

Comment: You are right about the quotation. Never the less the code works. Im asking about the methodology. If show_admin_column is supported in custom user taxonomy and if not what is the alternative?